# Selenium crashing with selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: newSession

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

OS:  Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-1066-aws x86_64)

Selenium Version:  selenium==3.6.0

Browser:  Mozilla Firefox 63.0

Geckodriver version : geckodriver-v0.19.0-linux64

### Expected Behavior -

Create a new firefox browser and do some steps - parsing the website.

### Actual Behavior -

Crashing with a log :-

```
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 151, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 240, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 308, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: newSession
```

Has anyone faced this issue before and has a possible solution ?

UPDATE :
Ran the following command : `geckodriver --log trace & curl -d '{}' 127.0.0.1:4444/session`

Log :-
https://pastebin.com/TirTNKrG

Comment: Never seen this exception before and don't understand what could possibly be the issue.

Comment: Try running the geckodriver with trace logging and invoking the "newSession" command manually:

geckodriver --log trace &; curl -d '{}' 127.0.0.1:XXXX/session

(Replace "XXXX" with the port shown when starting geckodriver)

Comment: @fzbd I removed the `;` from the above command you provided. Updated the question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I fixed the issue by updating the selenium python package and using the latest geckodriver.

Thanks @fzbd for all your help.

Additional context -

Refer to the compatibility chart here - https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html#supported-platforms

update selenium :

```
 pip install -U selenium
```

[update geckodriver](https://askubuntu.com/a/871077) (choose the correct version for your needs based on the above compatibility chart)

Check the versions for all components -

```
firefox -v
geckodriver -V
pip freeze | grep selenium
```

Comment: I had to also install the latest version of firefox

Comment: I had multiple geckodrivers in my PATH environment, it helped me to delete the old ones

Answer (score 12):

Thanks @skyfail.
Your answer helped me.
The following sequence was performed and resolved the issue.

1. To upgrade selenium run: `sudo pip3 install selenium --upgrade`
2. To upgrade geckodriver follow steps 1-3 from [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/871077)
3. `sudo mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin/geckodriver` , /usr/local/bin is usually in your PATH so no need to edit it.

Comment: Why should I sudo?

Answer (score 0):

In your log is the following line:

> 1540501901605 geckodriver ERROR   Address in use (os error 98)

Which indicates that the driver is trying to use a port which is already used by some other process. Since the log doesn't show which port it is, you can run the driver with `strace`:

```
strace geckodriver 2>&1 | grep -iE 'bind|getsockname'
```

In my case I get these lines:

> bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(4444), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
>
> getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(4444), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [128->16]) = 0

You can then check which process is using the port (for example):

```
netstat -tulpn | grep -i 4444
```

In my case returning:

> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4444          0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN      31471/geckodriver

According to a [issue about geckodriver port logging](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/401), you can let the os allocate a free port:

```
geckodriver --port 0
```

If all this doesn't work out, there may an incompatibility between your version of geckodriver and selenium, as this error in the log seems to suggest:

> geckodriver::marionette   TRACE   <- [1,1,{"error":"unknown command","message":"newSession","stacktrace":"WebDriverError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:178:5

I am using the following versions:

- firefox 62.0.3
- geckodriver 0.23.0
- selenium 3.14.1

Comment: `netstat -tulpn | grep -i 4444` gives me the same output that you're getting.

Comment: Just to rule out other instances of the driver, can you run a `killall geckodriver; killall firefox` and try binding to a different port? If you still hit an unavailable address, `strace` should output `-1 EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)`

Comment: I also edited the answer with a possible version incompatibility.